# JTable in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I try to put a JTable into a JScrollPane.

Here's my code :

```
String SQLquery="SELECT Name FROM Teacher";
PreparedStatement prepStat = con.prepareStatement(SQLquery);
MyTableModel model= AccesBDGen.createTableModel(prepStat);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

And the AccesBDGen's method :

```
    public static MyTableModel createTableModel (PreparedStatement prepStat)
     throws SQLException
{ResultSet data= prepStat.executeQuery();
 ArrayList <String> nameColumn = createNomColonnes(data);
 ArrayList <Object> row= createRow(data);
 ArrayList <Object> objectTypes = createObjectTypes(data);
 MyTableModel model = new MonTableModel(nameColumn ,row, objectTypes );
 return model;
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I try to display my JTable I have no problems. But when I try to display the JSCrollPane, it's empty.

Comment: Show more code. How are you added `JScrollPane`?

Comment: Yep, the problem is in code you're not showing us. Please fix this by creating and posting your [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly fix.

Comment: `When I try to display my JTable I have no problems.` - I don't believe that because the table header is not displayed if you don't add the table to the scrollpane and then add the scrollpane to the frame. The only add(...) statement in your code should be something like `panel.add(scrollPane)`. You should NOT add the table to a panel.

Comment: Your updated code still doesn't show any info about how are you adding JScrollPane?

Answer (score 0):

As Camickr says, I suspect it is probably down to you adding the table to the pane and not the  scrollpane!

When you add a component to another component in swing that component can only exist with that component and it creates bugs when used otherwise!

so at the end of your code you need to be writing

`getContentPane().add(scroll);`

and not

`getContentPane().add(table);`

or what ever applies to you!

Comment: I wrote the 
   getContentPane().add(scroll);

Comment: then you need to add more code to illustrate your problem!

Comment: unless you have added both add for the scroll and the table. In which case remove the getContentPane().add(table) to fix your problem

Comment: I can't put the whole code over there, that would be complicated. But I put all the code that wich has to do with this error, I'm sure.

Comment: @Raccoon `I put all the code that has to do with this error, I'm sure.` - until the problem is solved you do not know where the problem is. You have been asked to post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. And not a SSCCE should NOT include code for you database. The code should hardcode the creation of the TableModel and JTable. Once you understand how to do this manually then you replace the hardcoded logic with logic to do the SQL. It you had done this when you were asked 3 hours ago you would already have your answer. There is not trick to using a scroll pane.